# Using Spring's WebApplicationContext JUnit framework - How do I check the field value of an object set in my model?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, junit, model

I’m using Spring 3.2.11.RELEASE and JUnit 4.11.  In my unit tests, how do I check the value of a field of an object included in my model?  In my unit tests, I have calls like:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class MyControllerTests 
{

@Autowired 
private WebApplicationContext wac;

private MockMvc mockMvc;
…
@Test
public final void doMyTest() {
    …
    mockMvc.perform(get("/admin/mypage/search”) 
                    .param(“param1”, param1)
                    .param(“param2”, param2))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(model().attribute(C”modelName”, ???))
        .andExpect(view().name(“mypage/search"));
```

And in my controller, I have code that reads

```
   final MyForm myForm = new MyForm();
   …
   model.addAttribute(“modelName”, myForm);
```

But how do I check that the `myForm.getMyField1()` is equal to a certain value using the Spring JUnit test framework above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To evaluate a single object property try using a Hamcrest matcher to match agains your object attributes

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/admin/mypage/search”) 
                .param(“param1”, param1)
                .param(“param2”, param2))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(view().name("mypage/search"))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("modelName", hasProperty("myField1", equalTo("value"))));
```

or

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/admin/mypage/search”) 
                .param(“param1”, param1)
                .param(“param2”, param2))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(view().name("mypage/search"))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("modelName", hasProperty("myField1", is("value"))));
```